# Remove margins in highcharts pie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to remove the default height of a pie chart. Here is the code Im using

http://jsfiddle.net/554vf8te/

I want to reduce the size of the background container in yellow to only the height of the chart.
Here is the code I am using.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'In<br>Progress',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 50
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        colors: ['#88ad34', '#333'],
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '80%',
            data: [
                ['',   75],
                ['',       25]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use **solidgauge**? http://jsfiddle.net/q3jdag67/

Comment: Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/554vf8te/2/

Comment: Set `size` for the pie chart and `center: ["50%", "100%"]`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/554vf8te/3/ - size = 200%, because you display just half of the pie. If that would be the full pie, then `100%` will be enough.